# Standard Approach to Indicate NOT Part of WCF Data Contract?

Tags: .net, datacontractserializer

I understand that `DataContractSerializer` is opt-in... properties or fields that should be serialized are decorated with `DataMemberAttribute`.

Is there a standard, or at least common, method to succinctly indicate (to another programmer, not to the compiler) that a property should NOT be part of the data contract?

The `XmlSerializer` has `XmlIgnore` (out of necessity, since it is an opt-out serializer). Hibernate has a `transient` annotation.

What's the best approach to document for future maintainers "yes, indeed, I meant to leave off the `DataMember` attribute"?

Comment: My guess is that there is no standard approach and the best way is probably to create your own attribute.

Comment: As this is information to be conveyed to other developers I think the documentation of the type would be the best place for it.

Comment: My concern is that many maintainers don't always go read the documentation for the type before trying to "fix" things.  Sad, but too often true.  I'm trying to decide on the clearest, most succinct approach.  I considered the XML Doc comments... not a bad approach, and considered a proprietary attribute (probably better since it's right where they might be tempted to add a `DataMember` attribute they think might be missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the `IgnoreDataMemberAttribute` is what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx

Hope this helps.
Nate

Comment: That's a good idea. Technically the `IgnoreDataMember` attribute is for suppressing the default serialization of all members that takes place when you don't decorate your class with the `DataContract` attribute; but since it's just serving as a marker, any attribute could be used for this purpose, even your own.

Comment: Perfect.  Learned something new.